# Braintree-javascript - how to make drop-in ui form completion required?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, braintree

I want to be able to have behavior that is identical to the [required attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp)  for Braintree's drop-in ui such that if the user has not completed Braintree's drop-in ui form, then upon hitting submit the user will receive a notification and cannot progress.

I'm creating a form that looks something like this:

```
<form>
      <input type ='text' name='fullname' required>
      <!-- braintree drop-in ui form-->
      <div class="text-center" id="payment-form"></div>
      <input type ='text' name='email' required>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further testing, I found out that Braintree drop-in ui already has this functionality. It's just that if the bottom most field is unfilled then a notification bubble will appear over that field (in this case if you leave email blank). However if you fill out both email and fullname, then the drop-in ui lines will shake and turn red.